# Use same AppWidgetProvider for different variants

Tags: android

I'm supporting different variants of the same basic widget (dark scheme, light scheme, etc.) and find that I can't use the same provider class in more than one receiver declaration in the manifest, such as:

```
<receiver android:name=".otd.OtdWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/otd_widget_label">
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/otd_appwidget_provider"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".otd.OtdWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/otd_widget_label">
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/otd_appwidget_light_provider"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note that each receiver does declare a different XML file, which is where the different layouts are specified. I have worked around this by creating identical provider classes with different names (e.g., "otd.OtdWidgetProviderLight", etc.) but it would be more efficient to use the same provider class (internally, the provider can easily differentiate the variants by looking up the widget info via AppWidgetManager). Is there some way that I've missed to get around this limitation?

Comment: but why you need multiple OtdWidgetProvider in the manifest at all? cann't you set your scheme programatically based on some settings? (is  a previewImage attribute the reason?)

Comment: Yes it is for the preview image. That makes it more clear to the user than having a setting in the configurator, although I might decide to do it that way. For now I am using a workaround that is simple but ugly.